# Woocommerce products shortcode specific order

Tags: shortcode, woocommerce-offtopic

Is there a way to get products in the order of the IDs in the shortcode  parameter:

e.g `[products ids="53,68,1"]`

Display block with 3 product, where 53 on first place, 68 on second...?

Now I get products sorted by sku, name etc. Depending on order-by parameter, but I need specific order.

Answer (score 0):

```
     function woo_products( $atts ) {
         global $post;
         $product_Out = '';
                $atts = shortcode_atts(
         array(
           'product_ids' => '',// your product id goes here
         ), $atts, 'bartag' );
         $pro_ids = explode(",", $atts['product_ids']);
         foreach ($pro_ids as $key => $values) {
            $product_obj = $product = wc_get_product( $values );
            //call your html and data in $product out variable
            $product_Out .= '<div class="product_name">'.$values.'</div>';
         }
         return $product_Out;
     }
     add_shortcode( 'woo_products', 'woo_products' );
     //use this shortcode [woo_products product_ids="9,86"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, it's an older post, but I recently came up with the same problem, with the help of this topic [pre_get_posts with WooCommerce Shortcode Query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/310449/pre-get-posts-with-woocommerce-shortcode-query) I finally found a solution. Just add this filter to your functions:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_orderby' );
function woocommerce_shortcode_products_orderby( $args ) {
    $standard_array = array('menu_order','title','date','rand','id');

    if( isset( $args['orderby'] ) && !in_array( $args['orderby'], $standard_array ) ) {
    $args['orderby']  = 'post__in'; 
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[B4rT's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/317431/17826) has the right idea, but there's no need to code an additional filter for it. the `[products]` shortcode essentially uses `WP_Query`, so if you set the order to `post__in`, it will naturally order posts by the order in which they're passed:

`[products ids="53,68,1" orderby="post__in"]`